# close application from terminal using python

Tags: python, macos, terminal

How to close an application on macos terminal using python? I want something like this:

```
import os

os.system.close("app name")
```

Comment: `os.system("pkill appname")` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the best practice but I think you could first find the process ID of the application to close it. You can do so using [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). After getting application process ID, you can terminate them using [os.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) method

Note: For testing, you should comment out `os.kill` method call first just to make sure you don't accidentally terminate any critical processes

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess as sp

processes = sp.check_output(['ps', '-A', '-o', 'pid,args']).decode("utf-8").split('\n')

search_application = 'vim test.csv' # Sample application command name

def terminate_process(pid, application_name):
    print('Terminate process: ', application_name, '(', pid, ')')
    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)

# Iterate through the processes
for p in processes:
    p = p.strip()
    if p:
        pid, application_name = p.split(' ', 1)
        if search_application in application_name:
            terminate_process(pid, application_name)
```